# how to open multiple .dat files to process them in a loop?

Tags: python

I am using `with open ()` to open .dat files each time to process data. However, I would like to know how can I open multiple .dat files to process them in a loop? The goal is to process all .dat files and write the results to a single .dat file as output.

Below is the code using just a single .dat file, and a sample .dat file

```
5.577 #chord
14.043888 #alpha
10.275 #plane
1.00    0.000
0.98339 -0.015466667
0.96457 -0.00925
0.94365 -0.0057
0.92072 -0.00455
0.89589 -0.006016667
0.86929 -0.0106
0.84103 -0.018666667
0.81126 -0.030266667
0.78011 -0.045216667
0.74774 -0.06345
0.71431 -0.084716667
0.67996 -0.108333333
0.64487 -0.133333333
0.60921 -0.1587
0.57314 -0.183483333
0.53685 -0.206933333
0.50049 -0.228416667
0.46426 -0.247466667
0.42831 -0.2636
0.39283 -0.2763
0.35799 -0.285566667
0.32394 -0.291466667
0.29086 -0.29405
0.25891 -0.293383333
0.22823 -0.289583333
0.19897 -0.282833333
0.17128 -0.273366667
0.14528 -0.261383333
0.12111 -0.246966667
0.09887 -0.23035
0.07868 -0.211583333
0.06063 -0.190666667
0.04481 -0.167733333
0.03126 -0.143116667
0.02014 -0.116766667
0.01141 -0.088833333
0.00515 -0.0604
0.00138 -0.024316667
0.00    0.0
0.00138 0.02925
0.00515 0.069
0.01141 0.099166667
0.02014 0.1286
0.03126 0.15675
0.04481 0.18335
0.06063 0.2079
0.07868 0.230066667
0.09887 0.2497
0.12111 0.2666
0.14528 0.280733333
0.17128 0.291866667
0.19897 0.2999
0.22823 0.30485
0.25891 0.3069
0.29086 0.306166667
0.32394 0.30285
0.35799 0.297083333
0.39283 0.289116667
0.42831 0.27915
0.46426 0.267466667
0.50049 0.254366667
0.53685 0.240133333
0.57314 0.225083333
0.60921 0.209466667
0.64487 0.193516667
0.67996 0.17745
0.71431 0.16145
0.74774 0.145666667
0.78011 0.13025
0.81126 0.115333333
0.84103 0.10105
0.86929 0.087516667
0.89589 0.074816667
0.92072 0.06305
0.94365 0.052283333
0.96457 0.042383333
0.98339 0.033283333
1.00    0.000
```

```
import math


with open('Airfoils/ffaw3600.dat') as input:
    chord = float(next(input).split()[0])
    alpha = float(next(input).split()[0])
    plane = next(input).split()[0]
    mylist = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in input]

    zs = []
    ys = []
    z_trans = -0.25*chord
    y_trans = 0
    for line in mylist:
         if len(line) > 1:
                z, y = line.split(None, 2)
                zs.append(float(z))
                ys.append(float(y))
    input = tuple(zip(zs, ys))
zs = []
ys = []
for point in data:
    z, y = point
    zs.append(float(z)*chord)
    ys.append(float(y)*chord)
        
input = tuple(zip(zs, ys))

with open("Airfoils/ffaw3600new.dat", "w") as output:
    output.write(str(input))
```

Comment: Notice how "input" is colored red in the above code? That's a hint that it's a builtin. When you name your own variable the same as a builtin (like `input`, `map`, `tuple`, etc.), it's called "shadowing", and you effectively hide the original, losing access to it. It's good practice to name your variables something else.

Comment: Also you never define `data` before attempting to iterate over it, which should cause a `NameError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this and write to output file each time you read from input file.

This option is better if you are going to process a lot of files (but this will work only if you can process data from files and write it sequentially).

```
list_of_files = ["file1.dat", "file2.dat", ...]
with open("output.dat", "w") as output:
    for file in list_of_files:
        with open(file, "r") as input:
            # read and process data
            data = ...
            output.write(str(data) + "\n")
```

Also you can read everything from input files and then write to output file, but this will take more of your memory if you're going to write lots of information.

```
list_of_files = ["file1.dat", "file2.dat", ...]
for file in list_of_files:
    with open(file, "r") as input:
        # process data
        data = ...

with open("output.dat", "w") as output:
    output.write(str(data) + "\n")
```